# $\mathcal {L}(\operatorname e^{-6t}\cos(5t))=?$

Tags: laplace-transform

Find the laplace transform of the following equation
$f(t) =\operatorname e^{-6t}\cos (5t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: By one of the shift theorems, you have $\mathcal{L}\{e^{at}f(t)\} =F(s-a)$.  In your problem, we would then take  $f(t)= \cos(5t)$.  Thus, 
$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{-6t}\cos(5t)\} = \left.\mathcal{L}\{\cos(5t)\}\right|_{s\to s+6}=\ldots$$

> In the end, you should get $\mathcal{L}\{e^{-6t}\cos(5t)\} = \dfrac{s+6}{(s+6)^2+25}$.

Answer (score 3):

try writing $cos 5t$ as $\frac12 (e^{5it} + e^{-5it})$

Comment: also you might like to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Example_4:_Mixing_sines.2C_cosines.2C_and_exponentials

Answer (score 1):

ok let us use following formula for laplace transform

http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/c/9/0c9c50441866da37706842c765ad9859.png

after that we get following one

$$\int(cos(5t)*e^{-t(6+s)})dt$$

according to this

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28cos%285t%29*e%5E%28-t%286%2Bs%29%29+from+-infinity+to+plus+infinity
```

this does not converge,you can use also  formulas from this table

http://eeweb.poly.edu/~yao/EE3054/FormulaSheets_Test2.pdf

EDITED:
there is picture
[image]